# Probability: Complement rule.

Tags: probability

I have stumbled upon this example from the Newbold Business Statistics 8th edition that I am having a difficult time conceptualizing.

*In a promotion for a particular airline, customers and potential customers were given vouchers. A 1/325 proportion of these were worth a free round-trip ticket anywhere this airline flies. How many vouchers would an individual need to collect in order to have a 50% chance of winning at least one free trip?*

*In order for P(A) to be at least 0.5, the individual needs at least M= 225 vouchers. One might guess that, if the probability of a win for a single voucher was 1/325, then 163 vouchers would be enough to ensure a 50%chance of a win. However, in that case one would be implicitly assuming that the probability of a union is the sum of the individual probabilities, **neglecting to subtract for double counting in the intersections (which in this case would involve more than one win from M vouchers)**"*

The calculations are attached to the image.

Could someone please clarify the case double counting that the author is concerned about?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgILi.png)

Comment: If you flip two coins, would the probability of getting at least 1 head be $P(H_1)+P(H_2)=0.5+0.5 = 1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The double-counting indicates the probability that you have more than one winning voucher.

As the solution suggests, the probability that a voucher is not a winner is $324\over325$, so the probability that there are no winners out of $225$ vouchers is $\big(\frac{324}{325}\big)^{225}\approx0.49989$.

By contrast, the probability that there are no winners out of 163 vouchers is $\big(\frac{324}{325}\big)^{163}\approx0.605$, so there is only about a $40\%$ chance of winning at least one trip.  Going deeper, the probability of winning exactly one trip out of $163$ vouchers is $163\cdot\frac{1}{325}\cdot\big(\frac{324}{325}\big)^{162}\approx0.304$, so there is approximately a $10\%$ chance that you win more than one trip when you have $163$ vouchers.

Comment: But isn't the solution from the example implicit that we need to account for double counting possible winning vouchers thus the 163 draws may not be enough to have a 50% probability of winning and 225 must be drawn, which makes no sense to me.

Comment: @JacobS I added a paragraph explaining in more detail why 163 isn't right.  Let me know if that doesn't address your concerns.